# What is the radius of the $12$ spheres surrounding one of radius $1$ if all touch each other?

Tags: geometry

A sphere of radius $1$ is surrounded by $12$ spheres of radius $1$. But a small gap is left. What is the radius of the upper layer of spheres if all the $12$ kiss each other so that no gap is left? I mean particularly the radius of a single sphere of those $12$. The radius of central sphere remains $1$.

Comment: I had this same question a few years ago :) If the solution I recorded is right, the golden ratio is involved :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider an icosahedron with edge length $2$. Then spheres of radius $1$ placed at the vertices of that icosahedron will touch one another. Compute the distance of one of these vertices to the center, subtract the radius $1$ of the spheres at the vertices, and you obtain the largest possible radius of a sphere which fits in the middle. Take the inverse of that and you know the radii of your outer spheres if the central sphere has radius $1$.

Looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron#Cartesian_coordinates), the coordinates of the icosahedron can be choosen to be those $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy $\{\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert, \lvert z\rvert\}=\{0,1,\phi\}$ with $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ denoting the golden ratio. It even has edge length $2$ as I assumed in my approach above. The distance of one of these corners from the center of the icosahedron is $\sqrt{0^2+1^2+\phi^2}=\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt5}2}$. Subtracting $1$ from that, the radius of the inner sphere is approximately $0.90211$. Taking the reciprocal of that, you get

$$r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\phi^2}-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt5}2}-1}\approx 1.1085$$